# js select hours for each day of the week

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am allowing a user to select hours for each day of the week through the use of lists.  Visually the lists are just boxes with 1am, 2am, 3am, etc inside them and when clicked are highlighted to show they are 'selected'.  To do this I add a class of 'hour-selected' to the li item.

I also need to keep track of what hours the user has clicked for each day (those with class 'hour-selected'.  I know this logic works as I have used this code before, but only for one day.  In this example, I need to show all days on the same page.

With a few changes to my original code I came up with this, but I feel there must be some optimization I could do to prevent the repeating js used to push selected hours in for each day, but I am out of ideas and thoughts to do this...

**html : (this would repeat for each day of the week with id different for day)**

```
<ol id="hour-select-mon" class="clearfix">
    <li class="">12am</li>
    <li class="">1am</li>
    <li class="">2am</li>
    <li class="">3am</li>
    <li class="">4am</li>
    <li class="">5am</li>
    <li class="">6am</li>
    <li class="">7am</li>
    <li class="">8am</li>
    <li class="">9am</li>
    <li class="">10am</li>
    <li class="">11am</li>
    <li class="">12pm</li>
    <li class="">1pm</li>
    <li class="">2pm</li>
    <li class="">3pm</li>
    <li class="">4pm</li>
    <li class="">5pm</li>
    <li class="">6pm</li>
    <li class="">7pm</li>
    <li class="">8pm</li>
    <li class="">9pm</li>
    <li class="">10pm</li>
    <li class="">11pm</li>
</ol>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#hour-select-mon li, #hour-select-tue li, #hour-select-wed li, #hour-select-thu li, #hour-select-fri li, #hour-select-sat li, #hour-select-sun li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hour-selected'); 
});

// get selected hours in array
var monHours = var tueHours = var wedHours = var thuHours = var friHours = var satHours = var sunHours = [];

$('#hour-select-mon .hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    monHours.push($(v).text());
});

$('#hour-select-tue .hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    tueHours.push($(v).text());
});

$('#hour-select-wed .hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    wedHours.push($(v).text());
});

$('#hour-select-thu .hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    thuHours.push($(v).text());
});

$('#hour-select-fri .hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    friHours.push($(v).text());
});

$('#hour-select-sat .hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    satHours.push($(v).text());
});

$('#hour-select-sun .hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    sunHours.push($(v).text());
});
```

Comment: `var monHours = var tueHours` is not a correct syntax first of all, and bound to raise `SyntaxError, unexpected token 'var'`

Comment: yes I caught that - `var monHours = tueHours = wedHours = thuHours = friHours = satHours = sunHours = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you want to collect all selected items at once you may use a code similar to this:

```
var selected = {};
$('.hour-selected').each(function(k,v) {
    var day = $(v).parent().attr('id').substr(-3, 3);
    selected[day] = selected[day] || [];
    selected[day].push($(v).text());
});
```

Comment: Being that selected is an array of arrays... how would I properly JSON.stringify this as I am posting with ajax to php?  Would JSON.stringify(selected) take care of all arrays within it?

Comment: Actually, this solution is better, as mine doesn't take care of removing an item when the li gets clicked again.

Comment: @user756659 Yes, JSON.stringify does take care of nested arrays. Besides, you can assign elements of this array to 7 variables like monHours = selected['mon'];

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var selectedHours = {};

$('ol > li').on('click', function() {
    var li = $(this);
    li.toggleClass('hour-selected');
    var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    selectedHours[parentId] ? selectedHours[parentId].push(li.text()) : selectedHours[parentId] = [li.text()]
});
```

selectedHours will have the following structure

```
{ 
    "hour-select-mon" : ["4pm", "6pm"],
    "hour-select-tue" : ["9am"],
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this, but this would interfere with other ol's which aren't used for this.  Also, I need to JSON.stringify the arrays as I am posting them to php with ajax... would that still work with an array OF arrays?